# Running python applications through 'pyspark' is deprecated as of Spark 1.0

Tags: python, pyspark

Basically, I have pyspark script as follows (says in `spark_example.py`):

```
import os
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

conf = SparkConf().setAppName('example_app').setMaster('local[8]')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ls = range(100)
    ls_rdd = sc.parallelize(ls, numSlices=100)
    ls_out = ls_rdd.map(lambda x: x+1).collect()
    print('output!: ', ls_out)
```

with following configuration

```
export SPARK_HOME=~/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6
export export PYSPARK_PYTHON=~/anaconda3/bin/python 
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=~/anaconda3/bin/ipython
```

I can run following script `~/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/pyspark spark_example.py`I get warning as following

```
WARNING: Running python applications through 'pyspark' is deprecated as of Spark 1.0.
```

I'm wondering how to properly run python script for Spark (i.e. not using `import pyspark`).

Comment: Ahh, I guess, it's simply `~/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/spark-submit spark_example.py`. Let me know if this answer is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Spark 1.0, you should launch pyspark applications using `spark-submit`.

While `pyspark` will launch the interactive shell, `spark-submit` allows you to easily launch a spark job on various cluster managers.

I recommend you read the spark docs.